# MS word Formula not running properly giving error Run-time error '5992'

Tags: excel, vba, formula, ms-word

```
Sub DelXRows()
Dim oTbl As Table, oCel As Cell, oRng As Range, StrTxt As String
StrTxt = "X"
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  For Each oCel In oTbl.Columns(3).Cells
    Set oRng = oCel.Range
    oRng.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    If oRng.Text = StrTxt Then oRng.Rows(1).Delete
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

This is the function that I use in MS word table to remove rows containing "X". Now problem is, I have some merged cells and this formula is not working giving me error :

***Run-time error '5992':
Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.***

Any possible way to remove this error or to ignore rows with merged cells?

Answer (score 0):

How about a completely different approach? (I think this would need some refinement, particularly to do with how you initialise the Find):

```
Sub findinTables()
Dim oFind As Word.Find
Dim oTbl As Word.Table
Dim strTxt as String
strTxt = "X"
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  Set f = oTbl.Range.Find
  While f.Execute(strTxt)
    f.Parent.Rows.Delete
  Wend
  Set f = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not deleting whole row, but only deleting the cell containing "X"

Comment: It deletes the whole cell here. But I guess there's a risk that .Parent is not always the same type of object. Id be interested to know what typename(f.Parent) returns on your system.